# Passing a TextBox.Text into command

Tags: windows-phone-7, command

How could I pass a parameter into command like this

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" />
                    <Button Content="Search" Name="btnSearch" >
                        <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <mx:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SearchCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                                   CommandParameter=txtSearch.Text />
                            </Custom:EventTrigger>
                        </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you use:

```
<mx:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SearchCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                   PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
```

In the handler you can cast the sender to a `TextBlock` and then query it's `Text` property.